# Querying a view using information schema and wanting to save resultset to a single Array [PHP]

Tags: php, sql-server, arrays

I'm querying a view as follows:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS sc
INNER JOIN sys.views sv
on sv.name = sc.TABLE_NAME
WHERE COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE '%x%'
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE '%y%'
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE '%z%'
and object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[vw_B]')
```

The result set from this query gives me a list of column names. I wish to place each of these into one array (using PHP), the methods I have been using thus far just create the array I specify with an array for each item in the result set. This is because I was using

> sqlsrv_fetch_array

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new array and add the values to it. For instance:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $k => $v)
{
   $new_array[] = $v['COLUMN_NAME'];
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you! I wish there was a more elegant way (not creating two arrays and rather saving results straight into the first array) but this has allowed me to carry on thank you.